# Everyone saw my rising the plateau?

Tags: grammar

1. Everyone saw **my rising** the plateau.
2. Everyone saw **my lifting** a box.
3. I saw **cat’s eating** cream.
4. I saw **John’s waiting** in the alley.

Is it permissible to use Gerund as object?

If not, is it a general grammar rule or just applies to the above sentences?

Comment: Yes, it is acceptable to use a gerund as an object. It is a noun after all. However, all of your sentences make no sense (except maybe #2).

Comment: FeliniusRex, thank you! can you please think of any sentence with gerund in the same function which would make sense. I constantly fail, if i use it as object, it means nonsense. That is why now i think, it impossible to use it as object.

Comment: "I remember his coming to open the factory in 2010." "I could hear her playing from the next room."

Comment: Kate Bunting, thank you! Is, in your example, "playing" Gerund? I thought it is a verbal noun. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Gerunds can be the object of a sentence.

So what is the problem with your sentences??

> He rose the plateau.

What does this mean? The verb "rise" is intrasative, except in the sense "cause to rise" so this means "caused the plateau to rise" which is nonsense.

> Everbody body saw my lifting a box.

Almost certainly they didn't see a lifting they saw you! "Everybody saw me lifting a box."  Otherwise you could say "Everybody saw my lifting of a box"

> I saw the cat's eating cream.

What do you mean?  "I saw the cat eating cream", or "I sat the cat's eating of the cream"  Either alternative is better than what you wrote.

> I saw John's waiting in the alley.

No you didn't.  You can't see "a waiting".  What you saw was John. What John was doing was "waiting in the alley".  So what you should say is "I saw John waiting in the alley".

So gerunds can be objects:

> He enjoys Jack's playing tennis.

but very often its better to use

> He enjoys Jack playing tennis.

or

> He enjoys Jack's playing of tennis.

Comment: James K, thanks a lot!!! James, but does it mean i cannot use Gerund as object with verbs of sensual perception. All my sentences have such a verb - see.    He heard my coming- should be wrong then, right?      "Everybody saw me lifting a box." /"I saw John waiting in the alley".- here you suggest, participle should be used, not Gerund. I take that on board.

Comment: @IRINA Be careful about making rules. I don't think senses or perception have anything to do with it. "I enjoyed hearing you sing last night." One thing: all of your examples, and (almost all of) those here, *include possessives*. There isn't a rule against that either, but it complicates some of the examples.

Comment: @IRINA  It's easy to come up with simple sentences with gerunds as objects: "I like swimming." But when we add components—"I like *your* swimming"—"I like your swimming *of the English Channel*"—sometimes it gets so complicated that a simpler construction is better: "I like the way you swim the English Channel."

Comment: Andy Bonner, thank you! I specifically chose possesive case, so that Gerund is clearly distinguished from participles. Thank you for your comments!